# How to implement a TAPI solution with Avaya

Tags: java, tapi, avaya, jtapi

I currently have a working CTI integration on a Samsung phone system, within our business. Our desktop clients are running bespoke java clients which receive messages from our bespoke server application which connects to the Samsung DCS System.

We are getting a new Avaya phone system in shorty and I want to get this to work with our existing desktop client system. Therefore, I do not wish to install anything new on the desktop clients. I want to write a replacement server application that connects to the Avaya, and then uses the current message process from server to client.

Can someone please let me know what API I should be looking at to write this server based application. It must be Java based.

The two key things required are;
1. The server must be notified of all numbers ringing on all phones, so t can message the relevant client.
2. The server must be able to dial a number, on behalf of client phone, to an external number.

Any pointers in the right direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

The API you need is JTAPI; you can find the documentation for it on Avaya DevConnect website: http://devconnect.avaya.com. You will need to register there but it's free.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the Avaya Device, Media, and Call Control SDK (DMCC) which is a newer, fully functional API covering media, monitoring, and advanced call control operations.  See for more information https://devconnect.avaya.com/public/dyn/d_dyn.jsp?fn=353.

This API is hosted off of the Avaya Aura AE server (AES) which is deployed with Avaya Communication Manager.  AES hosts a number of different API including TSAPI and Web Services.  Investigate this platform and see if it meets your needs.

Comment: Am I correct that this doesn't work with IP OFFICE 500

Comment: I believe DMCC does not work with IP Office 500.  A quick look at the documentation indicates "TAPI Wave Driver" is available to allow for control.  Never used it myself so i cannot comment specifically on that TAPI interface.